# Better description of "Tenacious Badge"

Tags: feature-request, badges, zero-score-badges

I just got the Tenacious Badge, and I clicked my way to find out what it was for.

I have read it ten times, and I still don't fully understand what I got it for. Maybe it's just because I'm Norwegian, but still, please, **write a better description**!

2 years later the description is still confusing:

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total.

Jeff wrote in a [blog comment](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/improvements-to-badge-system/#comment-48359) that it meant:

> You have more than 5 zero score accepted answers, and zero score
> accepted answers make up 20% of your total accepted answers.
>
> You can see why we didn’t include the full text here, I hope.. :)

However the description remains unchanged and is not in any way comprehensible even to native English speakers. Jeff's comment can be rewritten to make it absolutely crystal clear:

> You have more than 5 accepted answers with a score of zero, and these
> answers make up 20% of your total accepted answers.

This is a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: In the mean time, have a look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-is-each-badge#68258).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's not just because you are Norwegian. I read it several times and had to search meta before I understood it.

The Tenacious badge is awarded to someone who has answered other people's questions, where at least five of his answers have received no votes and are the accepted answer to the question.

Comment: You're missing the percent-rule, which isn't very clear too. 20% from what? All Answers? Accepted Answers?

Comment: I agree with @userunknown - all of the elements of it are opaquely expressed.

Comment: I just got this badge and it's still confusing. If my answers did not receive a score it doesn't necessarily mean it's one of the accepted answers? Or is it assumed that if it was a wrong answer it would have been smashed by downvotes and would have a negative score, so some score at least?

Comment: An accepted answer has a green checkmark.

Comment: Also, "more than 5" = "at least six".

Answer (score 13):

I think the most unclear thing is what the 20% is of. As user unknown already posted, you can reasonably read that as a percentage of either all your answers, or just your accepted answers.

If the devs want to keep the description a little more succinct (you've proposed easily the longest badge description on the site) while gaining some of the added clarity and explictness of your proposed wording, they could go for this wording:

> More than 5 zero-score accepted answers, making up more than 20% of your accepted answers.

There are already a couple of badge descriptions that are of greater length, like the ones for populist and the tag badges, so I can't see any reason not to swap the wording to something like this.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

> At least 20% of accepted answers have no votes (minimum of 5 no-vote accepted answers)

Comment: Technically, "zero-score" != "no votes", right? Given Jeff's description of the badge, I presume that an answer with one upvote and one downvote would count as zero-score (though it seems to be against the spirit of the badge).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of "total" (which is wrong), it should just say "all accepted":

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of all accepted.

Not much longer, more accurate. Simple.

Answer (score 2):

This was suggested almost 5 years ago and there apparently are better explanations on a blog mentioned above and also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99746/148587

Why not improve the wording then? I just got "Tenacious"ized and went looking WTF that 1-line explanation meant ;-)