# Why haven't I received the Tenacious badge yet?

Tags: support, zero-score-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long do Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges take to be awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696/how-long-do-tenacious-and-unsung-hero-badges-take-to-be-awarded)

According to the descriptions given for the Tenacious badge [here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69322/better-description-of-tenacious-badge), I think I am eligible to receive the Tenacious badge. So why haven't I gotten it yet? Or did I misunderstand the requirements?

Comment: Still weird to me that people are so anxious to get this badge.

Answer (score 4):

[Answers must be at least 10 days old to be counted, according to the precise rules.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) One of your qualifying answers was only given yesterday, so you will have to wait 9 more days until the badge is awarded.

Comment: @Cody It's 20% of accepted answers, not all answers, according to the Meta post.

Comment: Hmm, so it is. Never mind.

Comment: @ Cody Gray: I have 7 non-self answered accepted answers and out of them, 6 are zero score answers... So doesn t it fullfil the 20% requirement???