# Trying to understand the Tenacious badge

Tags: support, badges, zero-score-badges

I have seen a number of these, and hate to ask another one, but when I count my accepted answers, it seems that I should have the Tenacious badge. The fact that I haven;t means I have probably misunderstood something about it.

I have 6 zero score accepted answers, and 13 scored accepted answers. This should therefore count as more than 5 and more than 20% of the total.

Or does it mean less that 20%? Or exactly 20%? Or something else I have not understood?

Comment: Some points to consider: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696/how-long-do-tenacious-and-unsung-hero-badges-take-to-be-awarded/57834#57834

Comment: 10 Days! that would explain it, although I am not sure when I achieved my accepts. I will happily wait a little longer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We only check for answers *more than 10 days old* in this badge...so your earning it doesn't depend on luck of when the job ran (it doesn't run as often as others)...before an answer has the opportunity to get upvotes just after being posted.

As it stands now, you'd get the badge in 6 days.

Answer (score 9):

The [mega-list of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) says of the **Tenacious badge:**

> - silver; awarded once; same family as Unsung Hero (gold)
> - have more than five accepted answers with a score of zero, and have those zero-score accepted answers account for at least 20% of all your accepted answers
> - only accepted answers at least ten days old are considered
> - Community Wiki answers, deleted answers, and self-accepted answers are not included in any calculations

I count that you have 6 zero-score accepted answers and 20 total accepted answers.

However, your [*last*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777351/thread-context-switching-issue/6777412#6777412) zero-score accepted answer was posted on July 21st, which is less than 10 days ago.

That means you're only working with 5 zero-score accepted answers, which doesn't meet the criteria for the badge. It requires **more than 5** zero-score accepted answers.

Just wait 6 days, and you'll get the badge. :-)